# My laptop display is not working after login screen in Linux mint. What can I do to get it back?

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor

I'm using Linux Mint mate edition. I often connect an external monitor to my laptop by VGA. When the system boots up without VGA connected, I get login screen. After I type my password and continue, I get no display at all. I have to connect the external monitor to see what's happening. Ctrl +alt +f1 doesn't bring up any display. If I login with a different user, everything's fine.
I tried deleting ~.config/monitors.xml and rebooting.

Now can anyone explain me how to get my laptop's main display back to work? It's really annoying. Without external monitor I'm completely blind.

I was following this post but couldn't find any solution. https://askubuntu.com/questions/148725/laptop-screen-blank-after-login-when-external-monitor-is-not-connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitor settings might be in `.xinitrc`, try deleting/moving that file and see if it works, also you don't need to reboot running `pkill X` or `systemctl restart lightdm` will restart the X server.

If that does not work try running mv ~/.config/dconf ~/dconf.bak and mv ~/.config/mate ~/mate.bak, this should reset mate's configuration, I'm pretty sure this the only place left where the monitor configuration could be

Comment: Where can i find .xinitrc ?

Comment: It's in your home directory, you can just run `mv .xinitrc .xinitrc.bak`.

Comment: mv: cannot stat '.xinitrc': No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like you don't have a .xinitc so that isn't the problem, try connecting the external monitor and running `xrandr -q` to get a list of monitors and `xrandr --output (the laptop's monitor) --auto`, the internal monitor will probably be called LVDS1.

Comment: Tried it. No display on my laptop screen. My laptop display is called eDP. xrandr output shows 2 devices VGA-0 and eDP

Comment: Try running the second command with --verbose and post the output

Comment: Also can you tell me the brand and model of the laptop?

Comment: crtc 1:        1366x768  60.00 +0+0 "eDP"

Comment: Laptop model and brand: ACER Gateway 4250s

Comment: Try using mate's monitor settings and enabling the internal monitor.

Comment: It says : both monitors are on. I tried switching off and on my ext monitor . it worked very well. But i tried it for external monitor. But my laptop monitor is still off. One more thing:  i'm facing not a single problem with the other user. It is this user profile which is causing the problem I think.

Comment: Try running `mv ~/.config/dconf ~/dconf.bak` and `mv ~/.config/mate ~/mate.bak`, this should reset mate's configuration, I'm pretty sure this the only place left where the monitor configuration could be

Comment: I dont know how it got solved. Here's how i t was solved. I tried to do exactly what you said. Then tried systemctl restart lightdm and some error occured. Copied the contents of dconf from the other user(where both monitors are working fine) to current user . restarted my computer and alas! ... Now both monitors are up. Very very thanks. Problem solved.

Comment: May i ask u to edit the answer to add "Try running `mv ~/.config/dconf ~/dconf.bak` and `mv ~/.config/mate ~/mate.bak`, this should reset mate's configuration, I'm pretty sure this the only place left where the monitor configuration could be" this method, so that a new person trying to fix the problem need not go through the whole comment section. Anyway the the problem is solved.

Comment: Sure, I also kept the old one since that's also a very probable cause for that kind of problem.

Comment: Right. The other solution is also probable.

Comment: deleting and sudo pkill X worked for me. Thanks